# make draggable div property false in prototype

Tags: prototypejs, draggable

I have a div in prototype and it is draggable I want to make its draggable property false. How can I do it? Thanks.

```
<div id="answer_0_3" class="dragndrop_0 foreign dropped_answer" >Notebook</div>
```

My draggables are as follows:

```
var draggables = [];
$$('.answer.dragndrop_0').each(function(answer) {
      draggables.push( new Draggable( answer, {revert: 'failure', scroll: window} ) );
});
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions related to the [tag:prototypejs] library with [tag:prototype]. Read the tag wikis (see links) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype itself does not support Draggable, but it's often coupled with [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us).
If you refer to a [Scriptaculous Draggable](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/draggable/), then you need to call it's `.destroy` method:

```
// suppose you initialize your Draggable something like this:
var answer_0_3_draggable = new Draggable('anser_0_3', ...);

...

// later in your code
answer_0_3_draggable.destroy()
```

How do you initialize those Draggables anyway? Please show some more code thant your one-liner?